# How can I really center my text horizontally?

Tags: android, fonts, alignment

I have a Piano app with some round labels on it with the note names.
These note names need to be completely centered on the label.
I finally figured out how to do that vertically using `ascent` and `descent`. However, I am still not getting the horizontal alignment perfectly ok.

It is mainly about the rendering of single characters. Whatever I do, some of the characters are off. It's slightly, but it's there.

Notice how the E is slightly off to the right for example, and the B a bit to the left.

[image]
[image]
[image]

I am rendering the labels in `onDraw()`, not with custom views. I also tried with a `TextView` the size of the labels and using `Gravity.CENTER`, but this gave the same results. Also note that I tried `Align.Center` too.

Code:

```
usedPaint.setTextAlign(Align.LEFT); //Also tried it with Center
Rect textBounds = new Rect();
usedPaint.getTextBounds(infoText, 0, infoText.length(), textBounds);
float textWidth = usedPaint.measureText(infoText);
canvas.drawText(infoText, circleX - (0.5F * textWidth),  circleY - ((usedPaint.descent() + usedPaint.ascent())/2),
                usedPaint);
canvas.drawRect((circleX - (0.5F* textWidth)), circleY - (0.5F * textBounds.height()), circleX + (0.5F * textWidth), circleY + (0.5F * textBounds.height()), otherPaint);
```

The drawn box's width is the result of `measureText`. At the `E` character you see that somehow it measures some whitespace on the left, making the character drift off to the right.

This is using the standard font on Android 4.0.3. Using a custom TTF font results in the same kind of issues, but different for each character.

I am wondering what else I can do? (Besides getting over it ;) )

Answer (score 0):

with center align just change canvas.drawText(infoText,
circleX - (0.5F * textWidth), ... to canvas.drawText(infoText,
circleX, ...

Comment: Yes, I did that too. It gives the same result.

Comment: just for test try longer texts e.g."eeeee" instead of "e" and try with and without width*0.5